# How to show activities inside of a running activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to show my activities inside of a running activity. I need something like frame in html language that is used for showing other pages inside a page. I know Tabhost has this ability. Which one of other controls has this ability?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google introduced [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) in Android 3.0 and upper to create a portion of user interface in an Activity. But it is not two Activity, becuase activity <> window. For lower version you can manually load xml layout in your activity.

Comment: do you mean that the only available thing is tabhost in lower versions?

Answer (score 0):

The [Fragment API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) is really your best choice, it's quite easy to use and you can dynamicly add them to your Activity Layout (take a look to [Framgent For All - google Article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html)) by code using the FragmentManager, this feature it's since 3.0 altough Google also released a pretty nice Compatibility Package that you can download out of the SDK Manager and added to your project like this [Fragment For All](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html):

[image]